# Turn off error messages android

Tags: android, ims

Does anyone know any apps that let you turn off error messages ie: `com.soandsoapp.whatever has stopped`. I'm on a rooted android system and am guessing there's some way to make the annoying ones go away. I'm not reinstalling imslogger.

Comment: This site is aimed at programming related problems. You could try http://superuser.com/ or http://android.stackexchange.com/ for a better audience.